# C# Activator.CreateInstance - how to create second instance of an existing object?

Tags: c#, activator, createinstance

I use Activator class to create new instances of a third party app (a c++ .exe)

The definition of the Activator class is: Contains methods to create types of objects locally or remotely, or *obtain references to existing remote objects*.

If I create multiple instances of my app, I'd like each instance of my app to reference a seperate instance of the third party app.  What is happening, is that each instance of my app references the same instance of the third party app (the third party instance being created when I run the first instance of my app.)

How do I force the third party app to create a separate instance of itself for each instance of my app?

Comment: What do you mean by `second instance of an already existing object` ???

Comment: Use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)

Comment: If you use Activator.CreateInstance to create an instance of a com object and then want to create a second instance of that com object.

Comment: How is AutoMapper going to enforce creation of a second instance of an existing object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Activator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator(v=vs.110).aspx) class in fact is defined as "Contains methods to create types of objects locally or remotely" but that is written poorly and it would be more accurate to say "Contains method to create objects based on supplied type information". If you are using remote objects and ".NET remoting" to bind in-process proxies to the remote objects, then the decision about when the remote object is instantiated is made by the remote process, not the calling process. If it defines a singleton instance, then all calls using Activator to bind to it will bind to the singleton exposed instance; otherwise calls will create a new instance in the remote process each time.

Comment: Thank you.  So I need to be looking for a property (hopefully) on the remote to indicate that I would like a new instance created each time - or would that be too easy to hope for?

Comment: On [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647428.aspx) search for "There are two activation modes for server-activated objects: Singletonand SingleCall." and read from there. The sample shows how to do what you want. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3198/Remoting-Singleton) is another example.

Comment: Yep, this is it.  Third party app developer confirms singleton.  Thanks for your assistance.